# Rearrange distance matrix into block form in python

Tags: python

Consider this very simple example in  which I calculate the pairwise distance matrix of some data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0, 1], [5, 6], [5, 6], [5,6], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
dist = pairwise_distances(data)

plt.imshow(dist)
```

[image: Distance matrix]

How do I get this matrix to be *as diagonal as possible*? I.e. it should look like this:
[image: Expected output]

This seems to be such a common task that there must be a `scipy` or `sklearn` function but I couldn't find any. 
Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
To be clear: I want the matrix to be ordered according to the distance values themselves.

Clustering the rows and columns simultaneously would achieve that but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: mmm, just sort the list. `data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))`

Comment: That is already helpful thanks!
But for more complicated data, `(x[0], x[1])` and `(x[1], x[0])` will result in different distance matrices. I would like the distance matrix to be ordered by the distance itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be as if what you are trying to do is somehow equivalent to [clustering algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) - i.e. to group elements that are close together, forming multiple clusters of elements. Once you have these clusters, the distance within each cluster should be small compared to the rest of the distances, and then you would just arrange blocks for each groups.

You may want to take a look at a nice comparison of clustering algorithms that are **already implemented in Python** [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html); whereas some of the clustering algorithms require you to specify in advance how many clusters you are expecting, some others have perhaps easier to control parameters.

With clustering, your algorithm should be:

1. Compute the clusters
2. Reorder the elements so that they are ordered by cluster blocks (i.e. [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,...])
3. The diagonal should now theoretically be very low compared to other values

How to order elements within each cluster, or how to order the clusters, is perhaps not well defined enough (as we need a proper definition of what's "diagonal as possible"), but see if this works for you?

Comment: Thank you for the long answer!
I thought that I could somehow rearrange the distance matrix without using clustering but I guess that won't work.